# Unexpected behaviour when applying rolling operation on a dataframe with no data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rolling-computation

Consider the following code

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.date_range('2024-01-01 00:00',
                                           '2024-01-02 00:00',
                                           freq='1H'),
                    'data' : np.random.rand(25)})

data.rolling(window='3H', on='time').max()
```

This produces, as expected, the following dataframe

| time | data |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-01-01 00:00:00 | 0.826762 |
| 2024-01-01 01:00:00 | 0.826762 |
| 2024-01-01 02:00:00 | 0.826762 |
| 2024-01-01 03:00:00 | 0.792733 |
| 2024-01-01 04:00:00 | 0.618498 |
| ... | ... |

If I remove the `data` column and apply the same operation

```py
data.drop(columns=['data']).rolling('3H', on='time').max()
```

I get no errors or warnings and, as result, a Dataframe with just the original `RangeIndex` and no columns in it. I would have expected the function to return the original untouched dataframe.

I understand what I'm doing doesn't make sense, because the input Dataframe does not contain any data to apply the rolling operation to, but shouldn't the function returns the input Dataframe (so with the time column) instead than removing it from the results?

In my case I was using the same function over a dataframe that sometimes didn't contain that column, and this unexpected return value was causing the whole pipeline afterwards to fail because it couldn't find the time column anymore.

Comment: "but shouldn't the function returns the input Dataframe (so with the time column) instead than removing it from the results?" I don't understand your reasoning for expecting this. (Anyway, did you try checking the result of the `.rolling` call, before applying `max`?)

Comment: My reasoning suggests that applying a `rolling` operation using `on='time'` on a dataframe that only has `time` column should return the same dataframe untouched, as there is no column to apply the operation on. Why is it more reasonable to instead remove the `time` column then? This way it would be consistent with the behaviour of the function when there is at least 1 column on which to apply the `rolling` operation, because in this case the `time` column is also returned together with the `data` column. But again, I could be completely wrong...